# How to add portion of timestamp to Fluentd output file format

Tags: linux, logging, amazon-s3, fluentd

How to add certain portion of time stamp to output file generated by fluentd?

In the config file:
s3_object_key_format generic-logs/%{time_slice}/out-%{H}-%{M}-%{S}-%{index}.log

time_slice_format %Y/%m/%d

What i expect for example: out-21-15-45-02.log

What i get: out-%H-%M-%S-02.log

Note: I am completely new to fluentd.

Answer (score 0):

This is right from this link: [fluent-plugin-s3](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3)

I'm currently using this exact format, and it correctly makes the date time stamp in s3.

```
<match pattern>
  @type s3

  aws_key_id YOUR_AWS_KEY_ID
  aws_sec_key YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY
  s3_bucket YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME
  s3_region ap-northeast-1

  path logs/${tag}/%Y/%m/%d/
  s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_%{index}.%{file_extension}

  # if you want to use ${tag} or %Y/%m/%d/ like syntax in path / s3_object_key_format,
  # need to specify tag for ${tag} and time for %Y/%m/%d in <buffer> argument.
  <buffer tag,time>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluent/s3
    timekey 3600 # 1 hour partition
    timekey_wait 10m
    timekey_use_utc true # use utc
  </buffer>
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>
```